# How to convert double column pdf to word using python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

In my project I need to convert pdf in double column formats. Basically I need to convert them to text file and I used `pdfminer`, but the ordering is completely a mess (when it comes to double columns, viz,IEEE papers). I just tried converting a double column word (docx) file to text with docx, it works almost fine at least with text (not with tables and equations).
That is why I am thinking whether I can initially convert pdf to word maintaining the complete order as done by some online tools, viz, Nitro Cloud. But I need to do this conversion using python programming/ python packages.

Can anyone please give some insights.
Code using pdfminer (which I tried initially).

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO
from cStringIO import StringIO
def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):

   rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
   retstr = StringIO()
   codec = 'utf-8'
   laparams = LAParams()
   device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

   fp = file(path, 'rb')
   process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
   fp.close()
   device.close()

   str = retstr.getvalue()
   retstr.close()
   return str
p1="C:\\sample\\samp.pdf" 

c1=convert_pdf_to_txt(p1)
```

(pdf sample:http://www.iracst.org/ijacea/papers/vol2no62013/1vol2no6.pdf.)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the Python code you tried with pdfminer. Also a link to a sample PDF file.